# SQL, SELECT. Выбрать ряды с 40 по 100

Tags: sql, select, выборка

В заголовке просто пример. Когда есть некоторый список товаров и они выводятся по страницам, естественно выбирать все, а потом уже в коде разбираться со страницами мне кажется очень неэффективным. Вопрос не в там как вообще это сделать, а как сделать это красиво и оптимально. Курсором, наверное, плохо? Это же по одной строке за запрос дергать - нехорошо?

С другой стороны нужно знать общее количество строк, чтобы определить количество страниц. Но когда пользователь будет по страницам переходить, опять делать запрос... Что ли кэш сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `LIMIT offset, count`

`offset` с какой записи тянуть

`count` количество записей

Чтобы вытянуть 1ю страницу на 30 записей

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0, 30
```

Чтобы вытянуть 2ю страницу

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 30, 30
```

При создании простейшей пагинации `offset` = `(page - 1) * per_page`

Comment: А как при этом получить общее количество строк при запросе? Чтобы можно было показать общее количество страниц.

Comment: @Uraty использовать `COUNT(*) FROM table`

Comment: Спасибо ) И ещё, последний вопрос. Те же товары или статьи меняются относительно редко, поэтому получается, что пользователь будут делать кучу одинаковых запросов. Нужно ли мне писать под это какой кеш или БД сама этим займется?

Comment: @Uraty БД этим не займется, если информация обновляется редко, то её можно кешировать, вы можете кешировать всю страницу целиком, либо конкретный запрос, все зависит от конкретной задачи

Answer (score 3):

Зачем изобретать велосипед?
Есть же LIMIT, OFFSET.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition LIMIT 40, 60
SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition OFFSET 40 LIMIT 60
```

Comment: Это пока не велосипед, просто не смог нормально нагуглить ответ, делюсь просто размышлениями на тему )

Comment: Просто неверно сформулирован вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Что MySQL, что SQL Server, что Oracle, что PostgreSQL поддерживают синтаксис для подобного или позволяют это так или иначе реализовать посредством SQL. Своих велосипедов не надо.

Comment: Postgresql 9.5: select * from table LIMIT 10,10 ответил ERROR: LIMIT #,# syntax is not supported. Подсказка: Use separate LIMIT and OFFSET clauses.

Comment: @ilyaplot потому что select * from table LIMIT 10 [OFFSET](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-limit.html) 10

Comment: Не спорю. Я о том, что не во всех БД синтаксис одинаковый.